# How to pass variable from classes to methods in Django for every object

Tags: python, django, class, one-time-password

I'm manually creating an OTP authenticator using `django`. I have created a class which creates an otp and sends it to the user by email. I've not written the code to send email. I'll complete it by `send_email()` inbuilt function. Please look after the code in `views.py`, I would like to use another function to verify the otp. But once I create the same object in the second function it reinitializes the variable.

```
def register(request):

""" Other stuffs like password matching goes here """
""" This will be provoked first in production """

     g=globals()
     g["user" + str(request.POST['username'])] = OTPclass()
     g["user" + str(request.POST['username'])].send_otp()

def verify(request):

""" This method will be provoked once the user enters the OTP received in the email """

    g=globals()

    g["user" + str(request.POST["username"])] = OTPclass() 
#In this part the value reinitializes to 0, but I must get the otp which was sent to the user

    if(int(request.POST['otp']) == g["user" + str(request.POST["username"])].the_otp):
        return redirect(login)
    else:
        print(g["user" + str(request.POST["username"])].the_otp)
        return HttpResponse("<html><body><h2>OTP mismatch</h2></body></html>")

class OTPclass:
    the_otp = 0
    def send_otp(self):
        self.the_otp = random.randint(1000,9999)
    """ send_email() will be used here to send the otp to the user """
```

Kindly suggest a way to get the value which was sent to the user in `verify()`. Globally declaring a variable in `views.py` leads to overwriting the value when multiple users access the function.

Comment: Store the OTP in the database, i.e. make a model for it, or store it in the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not into django, but i was facing the same problem with Flask.
You could use sessions to save data from one request to another.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/

```
    # set password:
    request.session['one_time_password'] = 'secret'
    # check password:
    if request.session.get('one_time_password', False):
        if request.session['one_time_password'] == provided_password:
            # login
```

this might be one solution.

another idea is to memorize the OTP in the Class. (If you dont want to use an database)

```
OTP = OTPclass()
def register(request):

""" Other stuffs like password matching goes here """
""" This will be provoked first in production """
    OTP.send_otp("user" + str(request.POST['username']))

def verify(request):

""" This method will be provoked once the user enters the OTP received in the email """
    if(OTP.check_otp("user" + str(request.POST["username"]),int(request.POST['otp']):
        return redirect(login)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("<html><body><h2>OTP mismatch</h2></body></html>")

class OTPclass:
    memo = {}
    
    def send_otp(self, user):
        self.memo[user] = random.randint(1000,9999)
    """ send_email() will be used here to send the otp to the user """

    def check_otp(self,user, password):
        if user in memo and memo[user] == password:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

keep in mind, that this sollution only works with one thread/process.